# Multiple totals with one eloquent query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to get multiple totals from a database table?

**Table:**

| ID | is_active | clicks | impressions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n | true or. false | int | int |

Currently I have two queries:

```
$total_1 = Model::where('is_active', 1)->sum('clicks'); // output 2.000
$total_2 = Model::where('is_active', 1)->sum('impressions'); // output 8.000
```

Comment: where is the problem here? how to display the result or the data structure? anything wrong in 2 query, or as suggested below you can write a raw select as described

Comment: @JahStation For a dashboard page, all data is collected first. That is already a lot of queries.That's why we were talking about optimisation. And basically there is nothing wrong with two database queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with raw query:

```
$data = Model::selectRaw('sum(clicks) as clicks, sum(impressions) as impressions')
    ->where('is_active', true)
    ->first();

$total_1 = $data->clicks ?? 0;
$total_2 = $data->impressions ?? 0;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-methods

Comment: Thanks it works! I will exept in view minutes.